# Why is python sys.path different from ipython sys.path?

Tags: python

I've seen similar questions with no clear answer.  In my case I'm in a conda venv and both python and ipython derive from the same bin/ in my venv directory. They both launch the same version of python.  I have no path mods in my ipython startup.  The path differs by having one extra directory in ipython, and the regular python path has a duplicate in it for some reason.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about what differs. I'm running IPython myself, and right now, the only difference in the `sys.path` is that `ipython3`'s begins with `/usr/bin`, and has the empty string further down, between the `lib-dynload` directory and the user site-packages directory, while plain `python3` lacks the `/usr/bin`, and instead has `''` at the front of the of `sys.path`. IPython is a *massive* environment customization, I wouldn't be surprised if certain setups make tweaks to `sys.path`.